# Deployment of sample task fails in PCF

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar

I am trying to deploy the sample task app on SCDF@PCF.

Deployment fails with the following Exception :

Shell side :

```
No Launcher found for the platform named 'default'.  Available platform names are []
org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: No Launcher found for the platform named 'default'.  Available platform names are []



SCDF Server side :

   2019-03-25T08:00:33.81-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-03-25 13:00:33.815 ERROR 19 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request
   2019-03-25T08:00:33.81-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Launcher found for the platform named 'default'.  Available platform names are []
   2019-03-25T08:00:33.81-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.findTaskLauncher(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:199)
   2019-03-25T08:00:33.81-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:151)
   2019-03-25T08:00:33.81-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>)
```

Any ideas ? Do I need to set a launcher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you may *not* have configured a platform for Tasks.

Starting from v2.0, SCDF provides the flexibility to configure multiple platform backends for Tasks, so you can choose from a list of platforms where you'd want to launch the Task. You can read more about the feature from the release [highlights-blog](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/spring-cloud-data-flow-2-0-at-a-multi-platform-enterprise).

If you haven't already configured the Task platform properties, please use the [sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-cloudfoundry-deploying-using-manifest) `manifest.yml` as a reference.

If you have set those properties and you still see this issue, feel free to share the `manifest.yml` - we can review for correctness. Of course, make sure to remove sensitive creds before sharing it.

Comment: Thanx SabbyAnandan. That helped. I was using the wrong prefix : SPRING_CLOUD_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY  instead of SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY for the platform properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just as complementary information:

I got the same error by launch on a **Kubernetes platform (Openshift)** and could resolve the problem by adding the following snippet in the `application.yaml` from dataflow-server:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              dev:
                namespace: devNamespace
                imagePullPolicy: Always
                entryPointStyle: exec
                limits:
                  cpu: 4
              qa:
                namespace: qaNamespace
                imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
                entryPointStyle: boot
                limits:
                  memory: 2048m
```

Reference: [Documentation Dataflow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-tasks)